# How do I remove this jquery effect to nav bar in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using Mantra theme for my website [here!](http://www.bianlei.com/about/)

Wanna remove this beautiful(slow) animation effect but don't know how!(Was looking for it for an hour... I'm noob, sorry!)

[image: nav bar]

Comment: the frontend.js is the javascript that you have to change....this function....jQuery("#access .menu ul li").hoverIntent({
 over: function(){jQuery(this).children("ul").show(400);},
 out: function(){ jQuery(this).children('ul').hide();},
 timeout:400}
);
You can change the timeout to some lower number to make the slow animation a bit faster....

Comment: thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your cpanel and open the file (`js/frontend.js`)

Go to line 109

change the line with :

```
over: function(){jQuery(this).children("ul").show(400);},
```

will help definitely.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.It may helps.

In `frontend.js` file (wp-content/themes/mantrab/js/frontend.js)

// Menu animation

replace code

```
over: function(){jQuery(this).children("ul").show(400);},
```

with this

```
over: function(){jQuery(this).children("ul").show();},
```

Comment: that is essentially the same code... the default is 400... http://api.jquery.com/show/ ... it would need to be 100 or 1 or something super small even 0 could work.